# Multi inheritance for IOS

Tags: ios, interface, protocols, subclass, multiple-inheritance

I want create a class that can inherit from two custom class.
Do you have any idea to do this please?
Please see below my example:

first class:

```
@interface UIZoomableView : UIView
{
    UITapGestureRecognizer *_tapGestureRecognizer;
}
```

and implementation:

```
- (void)onDoubleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    CGSize newSize;
    CGPoint centerPoint = self.center;
    if ([self isSmall])
    {
        newSize = [self bigSize];
    }
    else
    {
        newSize = [self smallSize];
    }

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
        self.size = newSize;
        self.center = centerPoint;
    }];
}
```

Second class:

```
@interface UIDraggableView : UIView

    UIPanGestureRecognizer *_panGestureRecognizer;

@end
```

implementation:

```
- (void)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender
{
    ..
}
```

i want to create a custom view that can be zoomable and draggable.
Do you have any idea to do this please? (without copy code..)

I think something like protocols but i want default value for the base classes?
How can i implement this using protocol or something like protocols.

Thanks for any response!

Comment: Objective-c does not support multiple inheritance, you might find the best solution to be protocols.

Comment: How can i implement that please? i don't want property that is delegate.. and i want default value for example in zoomable view i want default small size, if the subclass not override the function, the class return (50,50).

Comment: There is no really good way of setting default values for a protocol, as it is supposed to be non-implemented. What you could do is to inherit from a class that implements the protocol, have a look at this gist: https://gist.github.com/paulrehkugler/9647085

Comment: You know `UIScrollView` is draggable and zoomable?  Perhaps you want to subclass that?

Comment: Yes i know, thanks, but i gave this example to understand how i can implement multiple inheritance using protocols or something like this..

Comment: Why don't you want a delegate? Using delegates (and nowadays using blocks) is a well-established design pattern that works a lot better than multiple inheritance. The whole idea is to avoid subclassing, not making it even more complicated by using multiple inheritance. And the other advantage is that the compiler supports it. For multiple inheritance the answer is "Can't have that, and we are _not_ sorry".

Comment: You can check this approach http://whackylabs.com/rants/?p=3 using message forwarding... As the author sais:
"For further info check out the Apple’s documentation, it’s a great read."

Answer (score 9):

Objective-C doesn't support multiple inheritance. You could use a protocol, composition and message forwarding to achieve the same result.

A protocol defines a set of methods that an object must implement (it's possible to have optional methods too). Composition is basically the technique of include a reference to another object and calling that object when it's functionality is required. Message forwarding is a mechanism that allows objects to pass messages onto other objects, for example, an object that is included via composition.

Apple Reference:

- [Protocols](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocProtocols.html)
- [Composition](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaDesignPatterns/CocoaDesignPatterns.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH6-SW15)
- [Message Forwarding](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtForwarding.html) (and specifically [Forwarding and Multiple Inheritance](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtForwarding.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008048-CH105-SW10))

So, in your case Composition might be a solution, below is the example code

```
@interface ClassA : NSObject {
}

-(void)methodA;

@end

@interface ClassB : NSObject {
}

-(void)methodB;

@end

@interface MyClass : NSObject {
  ClassA *a;
  ClassB *b;
}

-(id)initWithA:(ClassA *)anA b:(ClassB *)aB;

-(void)methodA;
-(void)methodB;

@end

@implementation MyClass

-(id)initWithA:(ClassA *)anA b:(ClassB *)aB {
    a = anA ;
    b = aB ;
}

-(void)methodA {
    [a methodA] ;
}

-(void)methodB {
    [b methodB] ;
}

@end
```

If you don't want to implement all the methods from ClassA and ClassB in MyClass, you can use Message Forwarding in MyClass to handle all the method invocations. Below works fine as long as ClassA and ClassB do not have any common methods.

```
@implementation MyClass

-(id)initWithA:(ClassA *)anA b:(ClassB *)aB {
    a = anA ;
    b = aB ;
}

//This method will be called, when MyClass can not handle the method itself
-(void)forwardInvocation:(NSInvocation *)anInvocation
{
    if ([a respondsToSelector:[anInvocation selector]])
        [a invokeWithTarget:someOtherObject];
    else if ([b respondsToSelector:[anInvocation selector]])
        [b invokeWithTarget:someOtherObject];
    else
        [super forwardInvocation:anInvocation];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 4):

The closest that you can get to multiple inheritance in Objective C is with categories.  These are a mechanism for adding additional methods to a class that already exists.

Note that this has some important limitations:

1. You can't add properties or ivars using a category, though you can use [associated objects](http://nshipster.com/associated-objects/) to get a similar effect;
2. The compiler won't tell you if you have methods with the same name that are declared in the class and the category, or in two categories, so you have to be careful to avoid name collision;
3. This won't appear as a proper class (because Objective C does not have multiple inheritance) so you won't have something in your code called `ScrollableZoomableView` which inherits from `ScrollableView` and `ZoomableView`.  That's not possible in Objective C (unlike C++ for example).
4. You need the `-ObjC` flag when linking files with categories, otherwise you'll get `unrecognized selector` errors when you run your code;
5. You can't get your code called during `-init` or `+initialize`, because those belong to the base class.  You'll need to initialize your properties explicitly.  You can still use `+load` though;
6. You can't intercept dealloc either, so you may need to be careful to explicitly deregister your listeners too.

You want something like this:

```
@interface UIView (Zoomable)

@property (nonatomic) UITapGestureRecognizer * my_tapGestureRecognizer;

@end


@implementation UIView (Zoomable)

-(void)my_enableZooming() {
   self.my_tapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(my_onDoubleTap:)];
   self.my_tapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
   [self addGestureRecognizer:self.my_tapGestureRecognizer];
}

-(void)my_disableZooming() {
   [self removeGestureRecognizer:self.my_tapGestureRecognizer];
   self.my_tapGestureRecognizer = nil;
}

-(void)my_onDoubleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    ...
}

-(UITapGestureRecognizer)my_tapGestureRecognizer {
    return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, @selector(my_tapGestureRecognizer));
}

-(void)setMy_tapGestureRecognizer:(UITapGestureRecognizer)value {
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, @selector(my_tapGestureRecognizer), value, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
}

@end


@interface UIView (Draggable)

@property (nonatomic) UIPanGestureRecognizer * my_panGestureRecognizer;

@end

@implementation UIView (Draggable)

-(void)my_enableDragging() {
   self.my_panGestureRecognizer = ...;
}

-(void)my_disableDragging() {
    ...
}

-(void)my_handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender {
    ...
}

-(UIPanGestureRecognizer)my_panGestureRecognizer {
    return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, @selector(my_panGestureRecognizer));
}

-(void)setMy_panGestureRecognizer:(UIPanGestureRecognizer)value {
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, @selector(my_panGestureRecognizer), value, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
}

@end
```